# Reassign a sequence number when column is modified by trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a table that stores some data. Each data row has sequence number grouped by Organisation and Year. the structure of this table below

```
| ID | Seq_num | Organisation | Year |
|----|---------|--------------|------|
| 1  | 1       | A            | 2017 |
| 2  | 2       | A            | 2017 |
| 3  | 3       | A            | 2017 |
| 4  | 1       | A            | 2018 |
| 5  | 2       | A            | 2018 |
| 6  | 3       | A            | 2018 |
| 7  | 1       | A            | 2019 |
| 8  | 2       | A            | 2019 |
| 9  | 4       | A            | 2017 |
```

I have 2 cases for this table:

1) to assign a sequence number to the new row

2) to reassign a sequence number when column Year is modified

 For the first case I just select max from Seq_num over Organisation and Year like this:

```
 UPDATE table
 SET Seq_num =isnull(CurrMaxNum+1,1) 
 FROM table t  
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Year, Organisation, 
    MAX(Seq_num) OVER (PARTITION BY Year, Organisation) AS CurrMaxNum
                FROM  table
                GROUP BY Year,Organisation, Seq_num) as num 
                on num.Organisation=t.Organisation and num.Year=t.Year
        WHERE (t.Seq_num IS Null OR t.Seq_num = 0  )  
    and (t.Organisation=num.Organisation and num.Year=t.Year )
```

For the second case I need  to reassign Seq_num if year is modified. For example, if I change year for `id=5` from 2018 to 2017, `Seq_num` should turn from 2 to 4, as 4 is equal to max number in 2017's group +1. 

 There is no need to reassign the other values. How should I get what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution. Two update-statements in trigger after update. Quite slow, but it works:

```
--for 2d case
UPDATE table
SET [Seq_num]=  NULL
FROM table Z 
    INNER JOIN Inserted I ON Z.Id = I.Id
    INNER JOIN Deleted D ON Z.Id = D.Id              
WHERE 
    D.Year <> I.Year

--for 1st case
UPDATE table
SET [Seq_num]=  s_num
FROM table Z 
    LEFT JOIN (select  t.* , isnull(MAX([Seq_num]) over (partition by Year,Organisation 
               order by [Seq_num] desc)+1,1) as s_num
               from table t  
                ) S on  Z.ID=S.ID 
WHERE 
    Z.[Seq_num] IS  NULL
```

So if `Year` changes, current `Seq_num` becomes `NULL`, then second  UPDATE statement assign new value for `Seq_num`

Comment: Good job using the max windowing. I need to get in the habit of suggesting that as a use case as it has been available since 2012.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment.

Why bother storing the sequence number?  You can generate it on the fly using:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by organization, year order by id) as seq_num
from t;
```

There are reasons why you might want to store the data in the table -- say, if the table is quite large and performance is an issue.  Or, if you might be deleting rows and want to maintain the original sequence number.

However, for a table with thousands of rows (and columns such as "year" and "organization" lead me to think the table is not that big), calculating on the fly is very feasible and much simpler.

Comment: The table is very-very large, and we have to maintain original sequence number

Answer (score 1):

I loathe triggers, however, a use case seems to always crop up. (I would still see if this is something that could be controlled in the `update stored procedure` for your table).

If you want a trigger solution then I would create an UPDATE only trigger and iterate over all the inserted and update the records in which the year value was modified. As a side effect, you have created a non-transparent business rule and if someone meddles with the triggers you could run into a trigger calling triggers which is bad.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trMyTableModified]
   ON [dbo].[MyTable]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @ID INT, @CurrentValueYear INT, @PriorValueYear INT, @OrganizationID INT

    DECLARE X CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY LOCAL FOR
        SELECT ID,Year,OrganizationID FROM INSERTED
        OPEN X
        FETCH NEXT FROM X INTO @ID,@CurrentValueYear,@OrganizationID
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

            SELECT @PriorValueYear = Year FROM DELETED WHERE ID=@ID 

            IF(@PriorValueYear<>@CurrentValueYear) BEGIN

                UPDATE MyTable 
                SET 
                    MyTable.Seq_Num = 
                    (
                        SELECT MAX(Seq_Num)
                        FROM MyTable T
                        WHERE
                            T.Organization=@OrganizationID 
                            AND 
                            T.Year=@CurrentValueYear
                    ) + 1 
                WHERE 
                    MyTable.ID= @ID
            END

        END
    CLOSE X
    DEALLOCATE X
END
```

**One Update Query to do checks and updates.**

This is not tested, however, you could check for the change, pull the max sequence and perform the update in one query. It may prove more efficient. The INSERTED AND DELETED should always contain the same amount of records, even when triggered by a merge statement, as the merge will cause multiple triggers to fire for each operation, update,delete...

```
    WITH YearChanges AS
    (
        SELECT I.ID,I.Year,I.OrganizationID 
        FROM 
            INSERTED I
            INNER JOIN DELETED D ON D.ID=I.ID AND D.Year<>I.Year -- Ignore updates where year has not changed
    ),
    WITH MaxSeq AS
    (
        SELECT Year,OrganizationID,NextSeqenceNumber = MAX(Seq_Num ) + 1
        FROM
            MyTable T
            INNER JOIN YearChanges YC ON YC.OrganizationID = T.OrganizationID AND YC.Year=T.Year
        GROUP BY 
            Year, OrganizationID    
    )
    UPDATE 
        MyTable T
    SET
        Seq_Num = YC.NextSeqenceNumber
    FROM
        YearChanges YC
        INNER JOIN MaxSeq MS ON MS.Year=YC.Year AND MS.OrganizationID=YC.OrganizationID     
    WHERE
        T.ID=YC.ID
```